# showing premium stripe subscription after trial ends

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I have an app in which I have successfully set up stripe payments, with a trial, and then after the 60 day trial, a 9.99 per month fee. However, once the 60 days is up, I want to give the user an option to have a 99.99 per year one time fee instead.

I have done this, but the problem is, if I go into the manage subscriptions page in my app, it gives the option for the 99.99 plan even if the 60 days isnt up, and then if I click update to move to that plan, it doesn't cancel the original trial, and then pretty much breaks my code after that.

code (just incase needed)

```
    export async function createCheckoutSession(){
  let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

      const checkoutSessionRef =  firestore
      .collection('customers')
      .doc(userID)
      .collection('checkout_sessions')
      .add({
        price: 'price_1Iav0JKDPaWWeL1yBa9F7Aht',
        success_url: "http://localhost:3000/successPage",
        cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/signup",
    });
      // Wait for the CheckoutSession to get attached by the extension
            (await checkoutSessionRef).onSnapshot(function (snap) {
              const { error, sessionId } = snap.data();
              if (error) {
            // Show an error to your customer and 
            // inspect your Cloud Function logs in the Firebase console.
              console.log(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
            }
            if (sessionId) {
            // We have a session, let's redirect to Checkout
            // Init Stripe
            const stripe = window.Stripe('pk_test');
            stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId})
            console.log("logged stripe")
          }
      });
    }
```

manage subscription function (firebase api)

```
  export async function goToBilliingPortal(){
  const functionRef = app
  .functions('us-central1')
  .httpsCallable('ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createPortalLink');
  const {data} = await functionRef({returnUrl : window.location.origin});
  window.location.assign(data.url);
};
```

is there a way to hide the 99.99 plan until the trial is up?

Comment: Can you provide more details here about how you're updating the subscription and what exactly is "breaking"? Without further information it seems like this would be entirely in your control to not show this upgrade option until enough time has passed.

Comment: @NolanH after I call this function, it brings me to the stripe page. I type in your details no problem, but once I get to my profile page, and click manage subscription , using the function above(I've edited my question to show), then it shows both plans. I am just wondering if there's a way from preventing that to happen, maybe even in the stripe dash?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to keep track of the `trial` status yourself and check it when generating Customer Portal links. While trialing, if you do not wish to allow the customer to change to another plan you need to create another Portal Configuration which disabled subscription updates ([ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/configurations/create#create_portal_configuration-features-subscription_update)).

During the trial you'd use this `configuration` when creating portal links ([ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/sessions/create#create_portal_session-configuration)). After the trial you can use another configuration when allows for changes.